# cv2.imwrite not saving image in desired location as expected

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I want to save a image file under two directory but it is not working as expected. it saves in the current directory. 
cv2.imwrite('directory1/directory2/photo_name.jpg', image)

Comment: Please share your code too. You can visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear... but:

#### Solution 1:

If you want to access the parent directory, you have to use `../`.

Example: suppose you are running the script under `c:/dir1/dir2/script.py`. To save to `c:/dir3/dir4` you have to use:

`cv2.imwrite('../../dir3/dir4/photo_name.jpg', image)`

The first `..` points to `dir1`, and the second `..` points to `c:/`. From there, you can access `dir3/dir4`.

#### Solution 2:

If you want to save in a subdirectory of your current working directory, you first have to create that subdirectory. Then save the file:

```
import os
os.mkdir('new_dir')
cv.imwrite('new_dir/test.png',bgr)
```

If this doesn't work, try `'./new_dir/test.png`.

It'is also better to use some try/catch:

```
path = "new_dir" # could also be "../../new_dir_outside"

try:
    os.mkdir(path)
except OSError:
    print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % path)
else:
    print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % path)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way to do this is by using 2 imwrite statements with each having 2 paths. This will allow you save the same image in 2 diedtories.